# Node Js Sql Error Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error

Tags: sql, node.js

file a:

```js
const sql = require('mysql');

require('dotenv').config();

const db = sql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME
});

db.connect((error) => {
    if(error)
    {
        console.log('Db Conenct failure', error.message);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log('Db Connect Success');
});

module.exports = db;
```

file b:

```js
const db = require('../utils/dbConnect');
exports.getAllSchool = (req,res) => {
   db.query('SELECT * FROM schools',(error,response)=>{
   if(error){
       res.status(500)
         .json({
             success: false,
             message: `Internal Server Error ${error.message}`
         })
       return;
   }
   res.status(200)
      .json({
          success: true,
          response
      })
   });
}
```

Receiving Cannot enqueue query after fatal error as response. This error comes when i use mysql with nodejs. It returns response for some api calls but then sends this error after some time